# problem when trying JavaFX EventHandler ActionEvent with JOptionPane on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, javafx, joptionpane

### after run this and press {play} button  java stops and not respond on Mac

so I don't know what is the problem , I tried it in another another device (macOS )and same result.
any one have an idea !

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyFX_event_1 extends Application{  
    public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        // Create a pane and set its properties
        HBox pane = new HBox(10);
        Button btn1 = new Button("PLAY");
        MyHandlerClass handler1 = new MyHandlerClass();  
        btn1.setOnAction(handler1);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(btn1);
        // Create a scene and place it in the stage  
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);
        primaryStage.setTitle("HandleEvent"); // Set the stage title  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage  
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
    class MyHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent e) {  
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "game will start");}    
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: NO ,    nothing. @B.M

Comment: First of all, why are you mixing JavaFX and Swing?

Comment: Don’t mix JavaFX and Swing.  There are complex threading issues which you are better off avoiding.  Use [Alert](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) instead of JOptionPane.

Comment: It's hanging because you're trying to show a `JOptionPane` on the wrong thread (swing windows need to be shown on the AWT event dispatch thread, not the JavaFX Application Thread). As others have pointed out, don't mix Swing and JavaFX.

Comment: Posting a stacktrace is helpgful as well

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: @Zephyr its a material code in my university to learn JavaFX,
It normally works in windows

Comment: @VGR thank u , alerts works .

Comment: @James_D Thank u very much , now I know why  I will try to learn Threading .

Comment: You don't need to learn about threading. Just don't mix Swing and JavaFX, as other commenters have pointed out.